# An application of Fredholm Alternative

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I have just started reading the Fredholm Alternative for finite dimensional spaces and I came towards an excersise that it reads as follows:
If $H$ is a Hilbert space and $T:H\to H$ is bounded, linear map, with
$\langle Tx,x\rangle >0$ for $x\neq0$ then prove that $T$ is surjective. My way of thinking was to use the adjoint map $T^*$ like that:

$\langle Tx,x\rangle = \langle x,T^* x\rangle >0$ , for $x\neq0$.
The last thing means that $KerT^* =\{0\}$ and therefore, $ ({KerT^*})^\bot =H$, which means that $T$ is surjective.

But I do have some considerations in case the dimension of $H$ is not finite:

1. Is the adjoint $T^*$ always defined ?
2. Why we have $KerT^*\oplus({KerT^*})^\bot =H$  ?

Propably the above hold as $H$ is Hilbert and $T$ is bounded, but I cannot understand how I can deduce those...

Any clarification or hint is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes.  It will be helpful to know the other terms for adjoint: "dual" and "transpose" (even for operators that are not matrices).  See  [Transpose of a linear map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose_of_a_linear_map).  For a full, excellent exposition (which addresses infinite-dimensional linear algebra despite the title), see [FDVS](https://books.google.com/books?id=qwslDwAAQBAJ&dq=halmos+finite-dimensional+vector+spaces+google+books&source=gbs_navlinks_s).  I don't recommend learning linear algebra from any other textbook (Halmos also wrote a problem book on the subject), nor going forward to functional analysis before studying linear algebra.

2) Because (see the FDVS book cited above for every italicized term) if $U$ is any subspace of an *inner product space* $V$, then $V$ is the *direct sum* of $U$ and the *orthogonal complement of $U$*.  (For now, see the last bulleted item under "Inner Product Spaces, Properties" in the article [Orthogonal complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement).)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice answer! As far as I can see that the linear operator $T$ is bounded, is irrelevant here to prove that it is surjeective ....Am I wrong?

Comment: I think boundedness is important.  The exercise says to prove that a bounded, *positive-definite* operator on a Hilbert space is surjective.  The closest result I could find was able to find is the more general [Browder-Minty Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browder–Minty_theorem), but they require that the operator be *coercive*, which is a stronger condition that positive definiteness.  On the other hand, they don't require the operator to be linear.  This may be an overkill.  The question you probably want is,

Comment: Can an unbounded, positive-definite linear operator on a Hilbert space fail to be surjective?  (Of course, for finite dimensions, boundedness is guaranteed.)

Comment: After watching around some books in the  net, 
at least the pages they let you see,  about Hilbert spaces,  I see that the boundedness is required for the existence of the $T^*$ , so you are right and thanks.

Comment: Thanks for doing the research and confirming: I wasn't sure and didn't have the time to look into it properly.